# Can I minimize $x^a + y^a$ by minimizing $x+y$? Is there such a mathematical identity?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, maxima-minima, jensen-inequality

I would like to minimize the following expression:
$$x^a+y^a.$$

I wonder if a mathematical identity exists where a minimization of $x+y$ implies a minimization of the above.

Where:

- a is a positive constant,
- $x > 0$,
- $y > 0$

It's my first attempt at posting a question and appreciate any help! Cheers

Comment: Is there no other constraint on $x,y$? Else you cannot really minimize as $x=y=0$ is forbidden and $\frac12x, \frac 12y$ is always better than $x,y$.

Comment: I guess i have to allow x=y=0, which will allow me to minimize the function! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For $a\geq 1$ you can use
$$\frac{x^a+y^a}{2}\geq\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^a,$$
which is Jensen for $f(x)=x^a$.

Comment: Thank you! I'll just allow x=y=0 which makes it possible for me to minimize the function!

Comment: @JingRong You can not because $x>0$ and $y>0$. I made what you wanted. Good luck!